# Show custom product price in listing page

Tags: product-list

I am developing an extension where I need to show discount prices of specific products on listing page. That products would be selected from admin end.

To display custom listing I have to replace the base file with below file of mine

`app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mytheme/catalog/product/list.phtml`

The list.phtml file is same as in base, but i have added some conditions for price display.

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a question how to change template for the product default block? Or you'd like to modify product final price?

Comment: I would like to change template for product listing

Comment: Price is on the separate template, so probably you'd better modify product::getFinalPrice method

Comment: How and where to modify the getFinalPrice() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify product price using custom logic you can rewrite getFinalPrice from the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

You can find example how to extend magento core class using, for example, this tutorial http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/